# Choice of (should / could / would / might) in the "so that" clause

Tags: modal-verbs

He used a false name so that no one **should** discover his secret. [source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/should)

I refused an invitation so that I **might** spend Sunday with you. [source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/might)

She burned the letters so that her husband **would** never read them. [source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would)

I close my eyes so that I **could** stop missing you. (from internet)

The dictionaries just provide definitions for each modal-verb in these examples.

Any difference in meaning or usage?

I think they are just ordinary meanings here. Why do the dictionaries list them separately as standalone entries? Just because they are used in the "so that" clause?

Comment: These modal verbs are close in meaning but it doesn't mean that they can always be used interchangeably. Trying to replace one of them with another usually results in a subtly different meaning.

Comment: In such contexts, *should* is archaic, and *might* is at the very least "starchy, dated".

Comment: Thx, that's what I wanted to hear. @FF

Comment: Maulik V shared some of his wisdom. You might develop your comment into a more elaborate answer. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: I posted my comment *so you could* learn something potentially useful about contemporary English usage. In that context, it would be splitting hairs to claim any semantic difference if I'd used *so you **should, might, would***. In other contexts I think the difference between *will/would, can/could, shall/should* is effectively GR. That's to say *"I joined ELL so I **could** answer questions"* is credible, but *"I joined ELL so I **would** answer questions"* is just plain "weird". Whereas *"You joined ELL so you **would** learn something"* can only mean the same as ***could***.

Comment: Nice guidance. I guess that asking for semantic difference is not always a good way of making an enquiry. Sometimes a little guidance may well be more beneficial than just a cut-and-dried rule. Thx again! @FF

Comment: Actually, every time I ask a question in ELL, I have thought about a potential answer to it. I just want to know to what extent my thought could match that of a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, "should" and "might," in this context, are not idiomatic. A native speaker of American English would not use either one in the sentence unless they were pretending to be (1) pretentious or (2) British, or unless they are part of a fixed phrase or construction that has preserved this archaic idiom: "I should think not!", for example.

As a native American English speaker, I would use "would" or "could." They do have slightly different meanings, but in context, the differences are unlikely to be important.

In the sentence:

> He knew that no one would ever discover his secret

the speaker is talking about whether a thing will happen. In:

> He knew that no one could ever discover his secret

the speaker is talking about whether a thing is possible. In practice, they are more or less interchangeable. If you want to understand the difference, consider this sentence.

> The smartest man in the world knew that no one would, because no one could, ever solve his devious puzzle.

Here, the speaker makes this distinction expressly: it will not happen, because it is not possible.

In my understanding, "might" is a British, and possibly archaic, variant with roughly the same meaning as "could," and "should" is a British, and possibly archaic, variant with roughly the same meaning as "would."

Answer (score -1):

*so that* here indicates the purpose of doing something in the first clause. *I'll wear an overcoat **so that** I don't feel cold.* As I said, *so that* here is used to show the purpose. I don't want to feel cold and that is why, I'll wear an overcoat.

Now your sentences. Each of them has a particular purpose and that's why those *modal-verbs* are used that way.

> He used a false name so that no one should discover his secret - He's **very much concerned** about hiding his identity. So, no one *should* know that.
>
> I refused an invitation so that I might spend Sunday with you - The person who refused is **still not sure** of spending Sunday with whosoever that 'you' is (but mind it, he has all the plan for that).
>
> She burned the letters so that her husband would never read them - She does not want her husband to read them **in future**.
>
> I close my eyes so that I could stop missing you (from internet) [looks a bit off to me* but still] - talks more about the **capability to stop missing** whoever that 'you' is.

None of these verbs are interchangeable as doing so will change the meaning though quite a little.

For instance,

> I close my eyes so that I **might** stop missing you - here, it'd change the meaning and will say that if you close your eyes, you might (may be, possibly) stop missing whoever that 'you' is whereas originally *closing the eyes enhances the capability* of stop missing whoever that 'you' is.

Also,

> I refused an invitation so that I **should** spend Sunday with you - Here, it completely removes the doubt or probability (which is in the original sentence) and puts *(moral?) responsibility or compulsion* (on the person who's refusing) to meet whosoever that 'you' is.

Comment: The person who refused is still not sure of **what**?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng edited.

Comment: I feel that **should** in the first example does not imply any obligation or responsibility.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng at times, it does. A parent telling his son, *"You **should** finish your homework by the time I'm back from office."* Anyway, I added *compulsion* to clarify it further.

Comment: you didn't answer my last two questions.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I did answer but not directly. They are separate entities and used differently.

Comment: I disagree that "might" in this case indicates uncertainty. Idiomatically, if you say "I cancelled the meeting so that I might spend time with you," you are committed to spending time with the person--it's not the same as "I might spend time with you, or I might play video games."

Comment: @chapka #1.2 it refers to *an unfulfilled condition* which *certainly* further refers to 'uncertainty!*   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/might?q=might

Comment: @chapka *"I cancelled the meeting so that I might spend time with you; Hey, why might? you are certainly meeting; *Might, because I'm still not sure about my luck you know! Last time I cancelled the meeting but then I met with an accident you remember?; While committing something to you this time, I don't want to leave any ambiguity, darling!* :)